# laptop screen doesn't work on the first boot

Tags: laptop, display

I'm facing with a strange phenomena.

when i turn my laptop on the screen doesn't work (it still black), then i turn it off (press and hold the power button) then i turn it on again then it work fine. This phenomena happen every time i turn my laptop on.

What is wrong with my laptop? is it having problem with cable or screen or main board?

My laptop is dell 6420. It is quite old now (purchased on 2011)

Thanks!

Comment: Update BIOS/UEFI if not updated yet.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks you a lot. but can you tell me why doesn't it on on the first boot?

Comment: Hardware initialization is done by BIOS or UEFI before the OS starts to load. But in the firmware can result in all sorts of issues and weird behaviors. This is the reason for the recommendation above. If the problem persists then it's likely an hardware problem.

Comment: A few questions.. I assume it worked at some point so when did it work last? What did you do between then and it not working? I actually disagree with GabrielaGarcia as the bios didn't magically become bad all of a sudden (unless you flashing it is the cause). More than likely something is failing or came disconnected (a physical problem)

Comment: Your disagreement has merit. Firmwares don't become bad all of a sudden unless it's a (bad) new version, flashed as you noted or when due to age and an abrupt shutdown the settings are reset and from then one manifesting a bug that were always there but haven't been triggered yet or corruption in the firmware itself due to reasons. Flashing the latest (and last) version may correct this problem or not, in which case it's definitely hardware.